# Button container is cut off when using Menu with .menuIndicator(.hidden)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, toolbar

I'm adding some sort options to my macOS app that shows a list of stuff.

I'm using a Menu inside .toolbar {  ToolbarItemGroup() {} } like so:

```
Menu {
    ForEach(SortOption.allCases, id: \.self) { option in
        Toggle(isOn: Binding<Bool>(
            get: { userSettings.sortOption == option },
            set: { newValue in
                if newValue {
                    userSettings.sortOption = option
                }
            })) {
            Text(option.description)
        }
    }
}
label: {
    Image(systemName: "arrow.up.arrow.down")
}
.menuIndicator(.hidden)
```

Here's the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2utL.png

As you can see, the hover state / container of the label image seems to be cut off. I suspect that it's caused by `.menuIndicator(.hidden)` which I'm using to remove the default chevron that shows up next to the icon (it looks ugly and is too close to the icon: [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz0pE.png)).

Is it possible to remove the menu indicator while leaving the hover state container intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can replicate the truncation of the button when `.menuIndicator(.hidden)` is applied. Adding the `.fixedSize()` modifier seems to fix it:

```swift
Menu {
 // etc
} label: {
  Image(systemName: "arrow.up.arrow.down")
}
.menuIndicator(.hidden)
.fixedSize()
```

Without the modifier:

[image: Toolbar button without fixedSize]

With the modifier:

[image: Toolvar button with fixedSize]

Comment: Thanks so much! Simple and effective.